# How to navigate into named query definition on IntelliJ

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, named-query

Is there any shortcut or any way of defining one to navigate into a named query definition from its name? For example:

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery("Account.retrieveAccountById")
            .setParameter("accountId", account.getId())
            .getSingleResult();
```

I'd like to know whether this is possible to access "Account.retrieveAccountById", which is defined in my Account class, through some shortcut like we do when we *Ctrl + Click* attributes.

Thanks in advance!